# Selecting parent/ancestor node based on value in child node

Tags: javascript, xslt

My company makes a publication which outputs a clients current set of diagrams,
You can search the publication for diagrams with a given attribute value.

This works but only if the value is contained in the first Attribute node.

Me and another fellow have been trying to fix it so that it searches all the attributes.

Here is the xsl snippet being used to search the attributes. It is looking in Folder Diagram and Shape Elements to see if a child Attribute element contains a the word entered by the user.

```
        <xsl:template name="testObject">
    <xsl:if test="(name() = 'Shape' and $includeShapes) or (name() = 'Folder' and $includeFolders) or (name() = 'Document' and $includeDocuments) or (name() = 'Diagram' and $includeDiagrams)">
        <xsl:variable name="objXMLLocation">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="name() = 'Folder'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@ID, '/folder.xml')" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="name() = 'Document'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@ID, '/document.xml')" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="name() = 'Diagram'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@ID, '/diagram.xml')" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="name() = 'Shape'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(../../@ID, '/', ../../@ID, '_files/', @Source)" />
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:if test="js:fileExists($objXMLLocation)">
            <xsl:variable name="objXML" select="document($objXMLLocation)" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$searchName">
                    <xsl:if test="js:containsKeywords($objXML/*/Properties/RepositoryName, $searchKeywords)">
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="render" select=".">
                            <xsl:with-param name="fullXML" select="$objXML" />
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$searchDescription">
                    <xsl:if test="js:containsKeywords($objXML/*/Properties/Description, $searchKeywords)">
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="render" select=".">
                            <xsl:with-param name="fullXML" select="$objXML" />
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$searchAttributes">
                    <xsl:if test="name() != 'Folder'">                      
                    <xsl:if test="js:containsKeywords($objXML/*/CustomAttributes/Attribute/Value,$searchKeywords)">
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="render" select=".">
                            <xsl:with-param name="fullXML" select="$objXML" />
                        </xsl:apply-templates>  
                    </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the Javascript function containsKeyword it looks to see if the substrings in the needle parameter which are search words entered by the user exists inside the haystack parameter which is the value of an element or attribute that the user is searching the publication for. I am myself unsure of what is going on exactly, but it appears to work correctly.

```
function containsKeywords(haystack, needles) {
        var ks = needles[0].selectNodes('//K');
        var n;
        if (haystack[0].firstChild) {
            n = haystack[0].firstChild.nodeValue.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < ks.length; i++) {
            if (n.indexOf(ks[i].firstChild.nodeValue) < 0) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

The xml being searched.

```
<Diagram ID="49ab6eb5-c51f-4e36-9495-869897ef0d0d">
  <CustomAttributes>
    <Attribute>
  <Name>Approval Status</Name>
  <Description>Document / Diagram / Object Approval Status</Description>
  <Value>Draft - Work in Progress</Value>
  <Datatype>Text</Datatype>
</Attribute>
<Attribute>
  <Name>Next Document Review Date</Name>
  <Description>When is this document to be reviewed next?</Description>
  <Value />
  <Datatype>Date</Datatype>
</Attribute>
<Attribute>
  <Name>Stakeholder View</Name>
  <Description>Select the Stakeholder View</Description>
  <Value>PMO</Value>
  <Datatype>Text</Datatype>
</Attribute>
```

The current xsl will render a link to the diagram if Draft is enter as it exists in the 1st Attribute element's Value child element. But searching for PMO will return nothing.

The problem is that the xsl will only look at the first Attribute element, when it needs to look at all the child elements in the CustomAttribute element.

We tried using a for-each to go through all the Attribute elements we had trouble traversing the xml tree to get the Diagram ancestor so that it could be selected for the render.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is absolutely unclear. I cannot see what the XSLT code is doing (you are showing only a very small part of the code) and it is not clear what you want to achieve. Also, it is not clear whether the JS code has anything to do with the your problem, or not. Don't expect the people who monitor and answer xslt questions to be good at JS -- so if JS is important, at least explain with words what the JS code is doing. In short, please, rework your question.

Comment: I would say that your 'js:containsKeywords($objXML/*/CustomAttributes/Attribute/Value,$searchKeywords)' function doesn't work as you think it does, or at least that is where I would look, but as Dimitre says, there is no way to tell as that isn't included

Comment: I have added the javascript back in I hope this makes it clearer or helps to eliminate possible sources of error.

Comment: The problem isn't in the XSLT code at all. It is in the JS function. THis is why I have removed the tags xslt and xslt and have specified the tag javascript -- it is very likely an experienced JS person will find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the same task could be done in XSLT. This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="CustomAttributes" name="search">
        <xsl:param name="pAttributes" select="Attribute/Value"/>
        <xsl:param name="pKeywords" select="''"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$pKeywords != ''">
                <xsl:call-template name="search">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pAttributes"
                                    select="$pAttributes
                                                   [contains(
                                                        concat(' ',.,' '),
                                                        concat(' ',
                                                               substring-before(
                                                                   concat($pKeywords,' '),
                                                                   ' '),
                                                               ' '))]"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pKeywords" select="substring-after($pKeywords,' ')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <found>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$pAttributes"/>
                </found>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this proper input:

```
<Diagram ID="49ab6eb5-c51f-4e36-9495-869897ef0d0d">
    <CustomAttributes>
        <Attribute>
            <Name>Approval Status</Name>
            <Description>Document / Diagram / Object Approval Status</Description>
            <Value>Draft - Work in Progress</Value>
            <Datatype>Text</Datatype>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <Name>Next Document Review Date</Name>
            <Description>When is this document to be reviewed next?</Description>
            <Value />
            <Datatype>Date</Datatype>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <Name>Stakeholder View</Name>
            <Description>Select the Stakeholder View</Description>
            <Value>PMO</Value>
            <Datatype>Text</Datatype>
        </Attribute>
    </CustomAttributes>
</Diagram>
```

Whit param `pKeywords` default value set to 'Draft', output:

```
<found>
    <Value>Draft - Work in Progress</Value>
</found>
```

**Note**: When param `pKeywords` is not set or is set to empty string `''` output all the node set in param `pAttributes`, so you can think about this template as a filter. Also, you can edit the ouput to make it usefull for your logic, as example: you could just output the test value for non empty `pAttributes`, declare a variable with the content of calling this template, test for the string value of this variable and apply the templates as in your stylesheet fragment.

Comment: How would I be able to return the root node using your code?

The diagrams are spread over seperate xml files and the xsl searches each one and then the current xml file is sent to the render template.

Comment: @ywm: this named template is a XSLT implemantation of your extension function (extension are slow, the script engine is loaded with every call). You can pass the node set to search into (param `pAttributes`), and a space separate list of keywords (param `pKeywords`). The output could be just a dummy string for test (like you do in `test="js:containsKeywords(...`) that you "store" in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have figured out what the problem was.

Here is the solution I will try and explain what is happening.

```
<xsl:when test="$searchDescription">
                    <xsl:if test="js:containsKeywords($objXML/*/Properties/Description, $searchKeywords)">
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="render" select=".">
                            <xsl:with-param name="fullXML" select="$objXML" />
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$searchAttributes">
                    <xsl:variable name="source" select="."></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:if test="name() != 'Folder'">
                        <xsl:for-each select="$objXML/*/CustomAttributes//Attribute">
                            <xsl:if test="js:containsKeywords(./Value,$searchKeywords)">
                                <xsl:apply-templates mode="render" select="$source">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="fullXML" select="$objXML" />
                                </xsl:apply-templates>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
```

This snippet is part of a template that is applied across all a different Xml file to what is being searched.

In the description search when something is found the Publication Node is selected for use in the render.
Since there are multiple Attribute nodes doing the same as the Description search will only search the first Attribute element. So using a for-each will go through all attributes but at the same time changes the context to the xml file being searched.

So inorder to send the correct bit to the render template, I saved the context before the for-each in the source variable and when I find a match I send the source variable to the render instead.